# jQuery Resizable change other elements' positions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I have 3 div inside one parent div , when you want to re-size the element for the first time , other elements' positions change ,
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WRL8u/2/)

here is my code :

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="element" >BOX1</div>
<div class="element" >BOX2</div>
<div class="element" >BOX3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent { 
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:#e0e0e0
}
.element {
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    background:red;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = 0;
    $('.element').each(function() {
        x++;
        $(this).draggable({
            containment: $('.parent')
        });
        $(this).resizable({
            containment: $('.parent')
        });
        $(this).css('left', x * 50);
        $(this).css('top', x * 50);
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WRL8u/2/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your elements have a `position:relative`, meaning each time one of the boxes is changed, it becomes absolute and is 'taken out' of the flow of the page, so the other boxes move up to fill in the space left by it.

Changing the `.element` boxes to `position:absolute;` fixes this.

```
.element {
width:100px;
height:20px;
background:red;
position:absolute;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/WRL8u/3/